# Why is my quickSort method giving me a StackOverflowError? Java

Tags: java, sorting, recursion

Here is my quickSort method. It consists of two separate methods: **one that takes a queue as a parameter (1), and one that takes an array as a parameter (2). Then it uses the parameter array to make the queue to be passed to (1).**

(2)

```
public static <E> void quickSort(
   E[] array,
   Comparator<E> comp,
   long start,
   long timeOut
) throws TimeoutException {
   Queue<E> queue = new LinkedQueue<>();

   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   {
      queue.enqueue(array[i]);
   }

   quickSort(queue, comp, start, timeOut);

   Object[] newArray =  new Object[queue.size()];

   for ( int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++)
   {
      newArray[i] = queue.dequeue();
   }

   if (System.currentTimeMillis() - start > timeOut)
   {
      throw new TimeoutException("Quick sort has timed out.");
   }       
}
```

(1)

```
public static <E> void quickSort(
   Queue<E> queue,
   Comparator<E> comp,
   long start,
   long timeOut
) throws TimeoutException {
   if (System.currentTimeMillis() - start > timeOut)
   {
      throw new TimeoutException("Quick sort has timed out.");
   }

   int n = queue.size();
   if (n < 2)
   {
      return;
   }

   // divide
   E pivot = queue.first();

   Queue<E> L = new LinkedQueue<>();
   Queue<E> E = new LinkedQueue<>();
   Queue<E> G = new LinkedQueue<>();

   while (!queue.isEmpty())
   {
      E element = queue.dequeue();
      int c = comp.compare(element, pivot);

      if (c < 0)
      {
         L.enqueue(element);
      }
      else if (c == 0)
      {
         E.enqueue(element);
      }
      else
      {
         G.enqueue(element);
      }
   }

   // conquer
   quickSort(L,comp,start,timeOut);
   quickSort(G,comp,start,timeOut);

   // concatenate results

   while (!L.isEmpty())
   {
      queue.enqueue(L.dequeue());
   }

   while(!E.isEmpty())
   {
      queue.enqueue(E.dequeue());
   }

   while(!G.isEmpty())
   {
      queue.enqueue(G.dequeue());
   }       
}
```

LinkedQueue Class:

```
import java.io.File;

public class LinkedQueue<E> implements Queue<E> {
    private SinglyLinkedList<E> list = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
    public LinkedQueue(){}
    public int size(){return list.size();}
    public boolean isEmpty(){return list.isEmpty();}
    public void enqueue(E element){list.addLast(element);}
    public E first(){return list.first();}
    public E dequeue(){return list.removeFirst();}
}
```

NameComparator:

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {    
    public int compare(Employee a, Employee b)
    {
        String nameA = a.getName();
        String nameB = b.getName();
        int returnValue = 0;
        returnValue = nameA.compareTo(nameB);
        if (returnValue == 0)
        {
            return returnValue;
        }
        else if(returnValue == 1)
        {
            returnValue = -1;
            return returnValue;
        }
        else
        {
            returnValue = 1;
            return returnValue;
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
Time to create unsorted array : 0 ms
Time to copy unsorted array : 0 ms
fvuvdm,xezvdfqvom,oqqoj,azhjksqjt,tburnf,mkyroq,yokgqrfsiz,mrexmktnz,dqbey,uvbipqag,
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at LinkedQueue.dequeue(LinkedQueue.java:29)
    at Sort.quickSort(Sort.java:256)
    at Sort.quickSort(Sort.java:276)
    at Sort.quickSort(Sort.java:276)
    at Sort.quickSort(Sort.java:276)
    at Sort.quickSort(Sort.java:276)
    at Sort.quickSort(Sort.java:276)
    at Sort.quickSort(Sort.java:276)
//this continues for many lines

C:\Users\jackm\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\jackm\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Can you provide the `LinkedQueue` class?

Comment: this happens if your comparator is buggy. Is it a custom comparator? Can you share it’s code?

Comment: Re your incredible comparator with all the redundant code, you can replace the entire body with `return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());`.

Comment: Just added the comparator class. Also, that is my LinkedQueue class. It just implements SinglyLinkedList which I can also post if needed. And `LinkedQueue.first()` doesn't remove an element from the queue, only returns the element.

Comment: Just noticed that your comparator is back to front. Why?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by that, but I have the return values changing because of the logic in the loop in the sort method, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Whenever you see StackOverflow exception, first thing to look at is if you have a proper condition that will unwind the recursion part.  You probably have an infinite recursive loop.

Comment: I don't think it can be infinite, because it will definitely remove at least one item from the list at each level of recursion. The first item will always compare equal to `pivot` and will therefore go into `E`. So `L` and `G` will gradually dwindle down to length 1, where the recursion stops. But I think he may be getting N levels of recursion not log(N) (see answer below).

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is in your comparator.

Consider this expression:

```
"dog".compareTo("and")
```

It will return 3. But your comparator is only testing for 0 and 1. It will go into the else case, when I think you really want it to take the `returnValue == 1` case.

Since your comparator returns 1 most of the time, most of the items you pull off your queue will wind up going into `G`, and the number of nested calls to `quickSort` will be about the same as the length of your input array. (Note that in your stack trace, most of the calls to `quickSort` are from the same line, which is probably the one that sorts `G`.) So if the number of items in your array is large, that could produce the StackOverflowError you are seeing.

It looks like you want your comparator to reverse the sort order of the strings. You should just use:

```
return -a.getName().compareTo(b.getName())
```

or

```
return b.getName().compareTo(a.getName())
```

Comment: Exactly so. `Comparable.compareTo()` isn't specified to return exactly `{-1,0,1}`, only `{<0,0,>0}`.